# Is it possible to use ExecuteReader() twice?

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, executereader

I'm programming a database manager for a gameserver called OTServer, and I'm having problems using executereader() the second time. Here's code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=" + f.GetText1().Text + ";Username=" + f.GetText2().Text + ";Pwd=" + f.GetText3().Text + ";Database=" + f.GetText4().Text + ";";
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE name = @Name", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);

        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            label7.Text = (string)Reader[1];
            label7.Show();
            label8.Text = Reader[5].ToString();
            label8.Show();
            if ((int)Reader[6] == 1)
            {
                label9.Text = "Sorcerer (1)";
            }
            if ((int)Reader[6] == 2)
            {
                label9.Text = "Druid (2)";
            }
            if ((int)Reader[6] == 3)
            {
                label9.Text = "Paladin (3)";
            }
            if ((int)Reader[6] == 4)
            {
                label9.Text = "Knight (4)";
            }

            if ((int)Reader[6] == 0)
            {
                label9.Text = "None (0)";
            }
            label9.Show();

            if ((int)Reader[3] == 1)
            {
                label10.Text = "Player";
            }

            if ((int)Reader[3] == 2)
            {
                label10.Text = "Tutor";
            }

            if ((int)Reader[3] == 3)
            {
                label10.Text = "Senior Tutor";
            }

            if ((int)Reader[3] == 4)
            {
                label10.Text = "Gamemaster";
            }

            if ((int)Reader[3] == 5)
            {
                label10.Text = "Community Manager";
            }

            if ((int)Reader[3] == 6)
            {
                label10.Text = "God";
            }

            if ((int)Reader[3] < 1 || (int)Reader[3] > 6)
            {
                label10.Text = "Unknown";
            }

            label10.Show();

            label13.Text = "Account: " + Reader[4].ToString();
            label13.Show();
        }
        Reader.Close();

        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @Account_ID", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_ID", label13.Text);
        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            label11.Text = (string)Reader[0];
            label11.Show();
        }
        Reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What kind of problems? Anyway try to dispose the command too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Suggested solution:** Try putting a `using` block around your `DataReader`, or call `Dispose` on it:

```
using (DataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
{
    // ...do something with your data reader... then finish by:
    Reader.Close();
}  // <-- Reader.Dispose() called automatically at the end of using block.

// ...prepare second command...

// the same again for the second command:
using (DataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
{
    // ...
    Reader.Close();
}
```

**Assumed cause of your problem:** The DB connection object may do some internal book-keeping to keep track of data readers. I've found out in a similar scenario that you're only allowed one `DataReader` at a time. So I believe the problem with your code is that, while you `Close` the `Reader`, you haven't explicitly `Dispose`d it, so the connection object thinks the first data reader is still in use when you execute the second one.

---

**Besides...** why not simplify this code:

```
        if ((int)Reader[6] == 1)
        {
            label9.Text = "Sorcerer (1)";
        }
        if ((int)Reader[6] == 2)
        {
            label9.Text = "Druid (2)";
        }
        ...
```

to a `switch` statement?:

```
        int x = (int)(Reader[6]);
        string label9Text = string.Empty;

        switch (x)
        {
            case 1:  label9Text = "Sorcerer (1)";  break;
            case 2:  label9Text = "Druid (2)";     break;
            ...
        }

        label9.Text = label9Text;
```

(That would save you quite a bit of repetitive typing.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming that your code is correct you shouldn't have problem in executing two readers as you show in your code. Maybe you have problems because of not disposing commands or something else. I recommend an approach like this (Example made with Northwind db):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Orders", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(2));
                    }
                }
            }

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You should clean your code when recognizing the type of player. Create an enum instead:

```
public enum PlayerType
{
    None = 0,
    Sorcerer = 1,
    Druid = 2,
    Paladin = 3
}
```

And then do the following while reading:

```
PlayerType playerType = (PlayerType)reader.GetInt32(6);
label9.Text = playerType.ToString();
```

Comment: suggest using a player_type, player_class etc.. table vs an enum